# Neo4j query execution exceeding specified timeout

Tags: neo4j, timeout, cypher

I am setting a timeout for Neo4j queries in the configuration, but it does not seem to work to a meaningful degree of accuracy. Is there a way to get Neo4j to timeout a query close (i.e., within ~10% of) the specified timeout?

I have tried setting [dbms.transaction.timeout](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.transaction.timeout), which seems to somewhat work, just not accurately.

For instance, if I set it to 2s, the query stops executing after around 8s. I have also set it to 10s, and had a query stop after 30s. Not a big deal, except on my real dataset I set timeout=3600s and I have a query <strike>that has been running for 2+ hours</strike> that ran for 5 hours=18000s.

I also saw a post about using, e.g.,

```
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.enabled=true
unsupported.dbms.executiontime_limit.time=2s
```

But same issue as above.

Are there any other ways to get Neo4j to timeout a query with a little more accuracy?

Comment: I think the timeout is only grossly inaccurate when there is an OOM issue, which is what was happening for me. I had a 1hr timeout set or a query without a problem and it timed out near the correct time. It definitely doesn't seem to have ms accuracy (one of the units you can use) heh.